# How to create vibration with customized duration on ios's objectiveC?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, ios13, iphone-vibrate

I am using UIImpactFeedbackGenerator and UINotificationFeedbackGenerator to make vibrations, but I can't control the duration, is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. You need to use CHHapticEngine and CHHapticPattern, which you can use to make custom haptic feedback. I have never used it before, so I can't exactly say how to do this for your specific scenario, but I know this is how you're supposed to do it. Here's the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corehaptics/chhapticengine?language=objc